# How to open PowerPoint Presentation in New Tab in ASP.NET MVC C# project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powerpoint, openxml

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application which have a some power point which I want to display it on new tab.

I had used openxml to read files but I don't know how to open it.

My code for reading the files:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string file = Server.MapPath("~/PPTFiles/Test.pptx");

        int numberOfSlides = CountSlides(file);

        string slideText;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSlides; i++)
        {
            // Get slide text.
            GetSlideIdAndText(out slideText, file, i);
            sb.Append(slideText);
        }

        return View();
    }

    public static int CountSlides(string presentationFile)
    {
        using (PresentationDocument presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(presentationFile, false))
        {
            return CountSlides(presentationDocument);
        }
    }

    public static int CountSlides(PresentationDocument presentationDocument)
    {
        if (presentationDocument == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("presentationDocument");
        }

        int slidesCount = 0;

        PresentationPart presentationPart = presentationDocument.PresentationPart;

        if (presentationPart != null)
        {
            slidesCount = presentationPart.SlideParts.Count();
        }

        return slidesCount;
    }

    public static void GetSlideIdAndText(out string slideText, string docName, int index)
    {
        using (PresentationDocument ppt = PresentationDocument.Open(docName, false))
        {
            PresentationPart part = ppt.PresentationPart;
            OpenXmlElementList slideIds = part.Presentation.SlideIdList.ChildElements;
            string relId = (slideIds[index] as SlideId).RelationshipId;
            SlidePart slide = (SlidePart)part.GetPartById(relId);
            StringBuilder paragraphText = new StringBuilder();
            IEnumerable<A.Text> texts = slide.Slide.Descendants<A.Text>();

            foreach (A.Text text in texts)
            {
                paragraphText.Append(text.Text);
            }

            slideText = paragraphText.ToString();
        }
   }
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Even if you can read the files, unless you write your own Javascript-based UI for displaying the data, you won't be able to display it in the familiar powerpoint format that people are used to. I'd say your two best options are: 1) allow the user to download the file and open it themselves, or 2) open it in Office 365 online (you can make a file public I believe).

Comment: @ADyson how i can open it Office 365?

Comment: You'd need to store it somewhere that office 365 can access. Then you should be able to get a URL to it. Then you can just direct the browser to that URL. There are a few ways to handle the process though. You can probably find more info online. If I have time I will have a look, if you're still struggling.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open pptx file in a browser. You should put your .pptx file in a directory on server. And link it to a button. When User Clicks on button. It Will open.

Comment: i tried to do that but the file downloaded not open

Comment: Most browsers will just download it, not open it. It's up to the end user to open it. Sometimes the user can change their browser settings to make it open the file automatically, but it's not in your control as the writer of the web application. This is for security reasons, so websites cannot go round opening random files on the user's device.